# Вопрос по питону, ошибка с "cl.exe"

Tags: python

Работаю над проектом и понадобилось использовать несколько библиотек, все они загрузились нормально, а вот последняя начала опираться не понимаю почему.Выдает ошибку:

> "error: command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory"

Вроде как уже всё перепробовал, и последнюю версию `pip` поставил и т.п., не хочет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что за ошибка и как решить проблему, спасибо!)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `cl.exe` - это не что иное, как компилятор Visual C++. Поставьте Visual Studio с нагрузкой для С++ и (опционально) запускайте команду установки из development command prompt.

Comment: @VTT Спасибо большое)